# Javascript returning items from a for loop in an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am unable to understand how I can access elements from an array in an asynchronous fashion. I have looked at

[Async functions in for loops javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456835/async-functions-in-for-loops-javascript)

and

[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

but to no avail.

My functions

```
export async function processUserAllMessages() {
    let messages =  await getAllMessagesByRoom();
    var message;
    for (let message_obj of messages) {
        message = message_obj.data;
        let message_ref = message_obj.ref['@ref'].id;
        if (message.to == get(user).username) {
            if (message.acknowledged) {
                await deleteMessage(message_obj);
            } else {
                let promise = await processMessage(message_obj);
                console.log(message_ref)
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}



async function processMessage(message_obj) {
    // code to process message
    return promise
```

Typical output

```
340877637764252236 
340877637764252236 
340877637764252236 
340877637912101449 
340877637912101449 
340877637912101449
340877637916295753 
340877637916295753 
340877637916295753
```

The messages are returned in the for loop multiple times. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. If you `await` a Promise (which you do at `await processMessage(message_obj)` then that promise is awaited and the resulting value is returned, so your `promise` inside of the loop isn't a promise, but the value that the promise resolved to.

Comment: `let promise = await processMessage`   Yes, promise will no longer be a promise, that is the whole point of `await` to get the resolved value.  It's a little unclear what problem your trying to solve here.. :(

Comment: @ivar  The messages are returned in the for loop multiple times

Comment: @Psionman Then either `messages` contains repeated messages, or the `// code to process message` isn't working correctly. Neither of which you have shown, so we can't really help you there.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. We can't tell why `getAllMessagesByRoom` returns duplicate messages.

Comment: In other words, your code looks fine, and the problem must be elsewhere that's not obvious from what you shared.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to reproduce and post a better example